# Why won't $compile work with service using a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-compile

Please have a look at this example, since it is the best way to explain the problem.

In this example **if you click the directive link, it does not compile the template, but instead displays it as "{{1+1}}"**.

On the other hand **if you click the "Simple link" it compiles the template and displays "2" instead**.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .provider('$popup', function() {
        var service = {};

        this.$get = ['$compile', '$rootScope', function($compile, $rootScope) {
            var template = $('<div>{{1+1}}</div>');
            service.go = function() {
                $(document.body).append(template);
                $compile(template)($rootScope);
            }
            return service;
        }];
    })
    .directive('popupLink', ['$popup', function($popup) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function() {
                    $popup.go();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        };
    }])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$popup', function($scope, $popup) {
        $scope.go = function() {
            $popup.go();
        };
    }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <a ng-href="/test" popup-link>Directive link</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="go()">Simple link</a>
</div>
```

My question is why isn't the `template` compiling with the directive? (but it does in the controller)

And how do I fix it so that it compiles in the directive also?

*P.S. Here is the jsbin link in case you want to play around with the code:*
http://jsbin.com/vuzutipedu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Try this way: `element.bind('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: By default what value is showing? Before clicking anchor tags?

Comment: is this technique truly being used in an app running angular 1.2?  That is a 3 year old legacy release, and many new angular techniques won't work in that version.  Conversely, some things that were necessary in 1.2 aren't necessary in the current version.

Comment: @AvneshShakya adding `bind` has no effect. It still does not work :/

Comment: @Mr_Perfect it shows the correct value "2" if added by default. Only when using directives, it does not work..

Comment: @Claies changing angular version does not have any effect. I've updated the code snippet to use v1.6 and still has the same problem :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive needs to do [`scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.click(function() {
        $popup.go();
        //ADD apply
        scope.$apply();
        return false;
    });
```

The click event handler executes outside the AngularJS framework. A framework digest cycle needs to be performed to execute the watcher for the `{{1+1}}` interpolation.

It works with the `ng-click` directive because that directive includes `scope.$apply`.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

## DEMO

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .provider('$popup', function() {
        var service = {};

        this.$get = ['$compile', '$rootScope', function($compile, $rootScope) {
            var template = $('<div>{{1+1}}</div>');
            service.go = function() {
                $(document.body).append(template);
                $compile(template)($rootScope);
            }
            return service;
        }];
    })
    .directive('popupLink', ['$popup', function($popup) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.click(function() {
                    $popup.go();
                  //ADD apply
                    scope.$apply();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        };
    }])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$popup', function($scope, $popup) {
        $scope.go = function() {
            $popup.go();
        };
    }])
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <a ng-href="/test" popup-link>Directive link</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="go()">Simple link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a simple thing and I wasted so many hours trying to figure it out. It's so strange that this never occurred to me at all. You really saved the day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `$get`, instead of `$compile(template)($rootScope)`

`$compile(angular.element(template))(angular.element(template).scope());`

Let me know if it works